# Reducing an array of dictionaries based on condition and price

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda, python-3.4

I would like to reduce the following list maybe using a lambda function. I know that I could first iterate over the entire list and split it into sublists based on the condition value. Then I would iterate over the sublists to get the minimum price.

```
price_list = [{'price':10.8,'condition':'new'},{'price':6.9,'condition':'new'},{'price':3.8,'condition':'used'},{'price':1.8,'condition':'used'}]
```

The final list should only contain one item per condition with the minimum price.

```
final_list = [{'price':6.9,'condition':'new'},{'price':1.8,'condition':'used'}]
```

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be particularly well formatted for stack overflow and may be better suited for a programming forum. 
I would recommend at least trying *something* and then posting your code here if you can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, side-note: Using `dict`s as anonymous objects is inefficient (memory-wise), and more awkward than using plain `tuple`s or an appropriate `collections.namedtuple`. This isn't JavaScript, where anonymous objects are basically string keyed dictionaries.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The above lines are just used to give an example. Data are received using a JSON API.

Comment: @KelsonBall I basically just need a starting point. Separating a list based on the condition and then iterating over each one just seems so ugly.

Comment: @PhilippBraun: Don't separate it then. Make a second data structure that maps `condition`s to minimum prices (or a `list` or `set` of all prices, your choice). Iterate your original list, look up the `condition` of each element in the `dict` and replace the value there if you found a cheaper one. A `collections.defaultdict(lambda: float('inf'))` would let you just do `for itemdict in price_list:`, `cond = itemdict['condition']`, `mydict[cond] = min(mydict[cond], itemdict['price'])` Only need to iterate your original data structure once, and no need to maintain much auxiliary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
li=[]
for c in {e['condition'] for e in price_list}:
    di={}
    di['price']=min(e['price'] for e in price_list if e['condition']==c)
    di['condition']=c
    li.append(di)

>>> li
[{'price': 6.9, 'condition': 'new'}, {'price': 1.8, 'condition': 'used'}]
```

---

As ShadowRanger points out, you do this in one iteration like so:

```
dd=defaultdict(lambda: float('inf'))
for itemdict in price_list:
    cond = itemdict['condition']
    dd[cond] = min(dd[cond], itemdict['price'])

li=[]   
for k, v in dd.items():
    li.append({'price':v, 'condition':k})
```

Comment: This iterates the input three times for the example case (once to construct the set of unique `conditions`, then once per unique `condition` to calculate the minimum). Which seemed to be something the OP wanted to avoid. Also, this is Python 3, if you must do this, you can minimize the work with set comprehensions (`{e['condition'] for e in price_list}`) and generator expressions instead of list comprehensions for `min` to avoid intermediate lists (`min(e['price'] for e in price_list if e['condition'] == c)`).

Answer (score 1):

I will do it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import sys
d = defaultdict(lambda: float('inf'))

for x in price_list:
    d[x['condition']]=min(d[x['condition']],x['price'])
[{ 'price':v, 'condition':k } for k,v in d.items() ]

#output:
[{'price': 1.8, 'condition': 'used'}, {'price': 6.9, 'condition': 'new'}]
```

Comment: The `defaultdict` callback should probably be changed to `lambda: float('inf')` since `float` values could (theoretically) exceed `sys.maxsize`. Of course, ideally, for monetary values, you'd use `decimal.Decimal`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks. Changed it.